# Shell Object with minimized execution in VBA

Tags: vba, shell, object, execution, minimized

I would like to minimize the execution of the shell window and the execution of the python script with the code below:

```vb
Sub RunPython()
    Dim oShell, oExec as Object
    Dim sriptPath, scriptName, datas, oCmd as String
    Dim weekNumber as Integer

    Set oShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    oCmd = "python.exe " & scriptPath & scriptName & " " & datas & " " & Str(weekNumber)
    Set oExec = oShell.Exec(oCmd)
    'We are waiting for the Shell script to be executed'
    While oExec.Status = 0
    Wend
    MsgBox "Hagrid notebook update completed"
End Sub
```

It is imperative to keep the status information of the `oExec` object. I tried to insert the notion `vbMinimizedFocus`, but it doesn't work. Do you have an idea to solve this difficulty?

Answer (score 1):

According to my tests, both of these versions make `.Status` available.

**Option 1.**  Using `pythonw.exe` instead of `python.exe` - it does not minimize the window, but runs it completely in the background.

**Option 2.** You could add 2 lines at the beginning of the python script:

```py
import ctypes
ctypes.windll.user32.ShowWindow( ctypes.windll.kernel32.GetConsoleWindow(), 6 )
```